# Make first letter of string in TextBox upper

Tags: wpf

How can I make first letter of string entered into a `TextBox` to upper in WPF. I would like to do this in xaml.

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" CharacterCasing="Upper" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
         Margin="300,151,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240"
         Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         TextChanged="txtName_TextChanged"/>
```

Comment: converter or formatter should do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the style doing the trick:

```
      <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Lower"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: this would have been very nice if it didn't uppercase all characters when "copy paste" a string